# Changing location of a wordpress plugin inside the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added the Like Button plugin to my wordpress page and it adds a like/dislike button at the bottom of my wordpress post.

I'd like to change the position where the buttons are shown (to below my post's title), but I can't find where the function that draws the buttons is being called.

Any way I can change that by editing one of the php files?

Thank you.

Comment: Find another plugins that suit your need, editing a plugin is not advisable, because it frequently updated on its core unless your are a developer of the plugin itself.

Comment: I just wanna change the position where it is loaded. I've tried finding another already with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to search plugin's source code for the `the_content` hook and remove it like this:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'same_function_name', 10)
```

Be sure that the last number is the same as the add_filter function, otherwise it won't work.

Then you can create your own function like this:

```
<?php
function my_new_button_position( $title ) {
    $button_html = call_plugin_function_that_was_in_the_content_hook();
    $title .= $button_html;
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'new_button_position' );
?>
```

The `call_plugin_function_that_was_in_the_content_hook()` is the function that was called in the content hook.